# Ошибка компиляции Java illegal start of expression

Tags: java, android, компиляция

При компиляции выдаёт ошибку в этом куске кода[image] в 7 строчке void var3_5;

```
public List<SipResponseType> getReRegisterOnResponseTypesList() {
            ArrayList<SipResponseType> arrayList = new ArrayList<SipResponseType>();
            Account.SipResponseType[] arrsipResponseType = this.nano.reRegisterOnResponseTypes;
            int n = arrsipResponseType.length;
            int n2 = 0;
            while (n2 < n){
                void var3_5;
                Account.SipResponseType sipResponseType = arrsipResponseType[n2];
                if (sipResponseType == null) {
                    Object var3_7 = null;
                } else {
                    SipResponseType sipResponseType2 = new SipResponseType(sipResponseType);
                }
                arrayList.add((SipResponseType)var3_5);
                ++n2;
            }
            return arrayList;
        }
```

Comment: А что, по Вашему, `void var3_5;` должно значить? Кроме того, исходя из приведенного кода, эта переменная НИКОГДА не инициализируется, но используется, что вообще абсурдно. П.с. типа данных `void` в java нет

Comment: походу Вам нужен другой декомпилятор, потому как этот косячит :)

Comment: А какой нормальный декомпилятор,  а то я сам не понимаю что он выделывает)

Answer (score 0):

Ключевое слово `void` используется только в качестве типа возвращаемого значения метода, который ничего не возвращает. Использовать его как тип переменной - нельзя.

Не очень ясно, что вы хотели написать, но, помимо вышеуказанного, вы ещё и не инициализировали переменную. И если замените её тип на, например `Object` или `SipResponseType`, что вы, наверное и хотели написать, у вас будет уже другая ошибка, вроде бы NPE.

Скорее всего вы хотели что-то такое написать:

```
Account.SipResponseType sipResponseType = arrsipResponseType[n2];
if (sipResponseType != null) {
    arrayList.add(new SipResponseType(sipResponseType));
}
```